# JSF - ValueChangeListener in Datatable

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

How to implement correctly a ValueChangeListener with UIInput Component within a Datatable, then i getting in a listener method get the row index has changed, new value and old Value

```
<datatable>
<column>
  <input value="item.unitPrice" valueChangeListener="#{bean.myListener}">
</column>
```

Changes, not necessarily generate POST to Server, Post may be generated by others events.

Any Help, Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind the datatable's value to a [`DataModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html):

```
private DataModel<Item> dataModel; // +getter

public Bean() {
    this.dataModel = new ListDataModel<Item>(loadListOfItemsFromDatabase());
}
```

with

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.dataModel}">
```

This way you can access the current index (and also the current `Item`) in the valuechangelistener:

```
public void myListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    int index = dataModel.getRowIndex();
    Item item = dataModel.getRowData();
    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your bean you should have the method like this:

```
public void myListener(ValueChangeEvent e){
    UIData data = (UIData) e.getComponent().findComponent("myDatatableId");
    int rowIndex = data.getRowIndex();
    Object myNewValue = e.getNewValue();
    Object myOldValue = e.getOldValue();
}
```

And now you have the row index, old and new values.